# Can Thonny run scripts as root on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, thonny

I'm trying to use the `keyboard` library within Thonny on my Raspberrypi Zero W. However I receive an error saying "*import error: you must be root to use this library on Linux.*"

Can Thonny run scripts as root to avoid this error?

[image: screen_image]

Comment: No, Thonny doesn't have means for running scripts as a different user or with sudo

Comment: perhaps you can start Thonny - whatever it may be-  as root

Answer (score 2):

- Go to menu right click on Thonny menu item.
- Click on properties
- Click on the tab 'Desktop Entry'
- Change the 'Command' field to `sudo /usr/bin/thonny %F`
- Click on OK button.
- Close and open Thonny.
- Important: You are running  Thonny as root, which means when you click on the save/load button it will by default show the Home of the root user. Make sure you choose your default user ( usually the pi folder )

Answer (score 0):

If you run Thonny as root you can.

So open a terminal and enter sudo Thonny

Comment: Running a whole IDE as the root user is probably not the best idea. I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal and use `sudo python program.py` to start the program.

Comment: Specifically, Can Thonny run scripts as root?

Comment: Try to run Thonny as root. If the IDE has privileges, it also can run other scripts using it.